# Trigger for Event/Activity

Tags: trigger, event, activity

I'm new one in development and trying to write below trigger but on Event (activity):

```java
trigger UpdateAccountType on Task (before update) {
    Set<Id> leadId = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task t : Trigger.new){
        if(t.WhoId != null){
              String s1 = t.WhoId;
               if(s1.left(3) == '00Q'){
                        leadId.add(t.whoId);
               }
         }
    }

    Lead lead = [Select Id, Type__c From Lead Where Id In : leadId limit 1];
    for(Task tk: Trigger.New){
           tk.Account_Type__c = lead.Type__c;
    } 
    
}
```

Thanks so much for your help. I tried to replace tk. to event., but it not working.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, I don't think there's enough information to really give you much help or direction. If you have written a trigger on `Event` based on this one (even if it isn't able to be saved and/or is giving you errors), seeing the code that's actually failing is important here. If you are getting an error message, please also include it (the full text of the error, including the stack trace. Don't try to paraphrase it.) You can add this information to your question by making an [edit].

Comment: Hi @DerekF, well noted with many thanks. And thanks a lot for welcome and your reply:))

Answer (score 1):

Your code has bulkification issues. Here's the corrected version of your trigger:

```
trigger UpdateAccountType on Task (before update) {
    Map<Id, Lead> leads = new Map<Id, Lead>();
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.WhoId?.getSObjectType() == Lead.sObjectType) {
            leads.put(record.WhoId, null);
        }
    }
    leads.putAll([SELECT Type__c FROM Lead WHERE Id = :leads.keySet()]);
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        record.Account_Type__c = leads.get(record.WhoId)?.Type__c;
    }
}
```

To change this to Events, change every instance of the word Task with Event.

Note that an Activity is either a Task or Event.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, AWESOME!! It works perfectly., I lost any hope to make this possible as i have no competencies on dev. Thanks so much. If you have any advise to give me to learn the triggers, please let me know. Great THANKS again for your help.

Comment: @Chloe I'd recommend you start with the [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_intro) and then explore other trigger resources on the trailhead. Also, [Getting Started with Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_intro_get_started.htm) is a good language resource for anything you don't understand in the code I wrote.

Comment: Love it. Thanks a lot @sfdcfox. I appreciate a lot for your help and for the links

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, i received following error message when deploying from Sandbox to Prod "The following triggers have 0% code coverage. Each trigger must have at least 1% code coverage.". In the list of that triggers the mine which you wrote but  it works well into sandbox. I tried to look for info in internet, but not sure to understand what exactly to do to increase the code coverage to at last 1%? Should i run the test? if yes, where? in developper console? Sorry for stupid questions, i discover the triggers. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Chloe You need to write a [unit test](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_testing/apex_testing_intro). Basically, you write code that uses `@isTest` and then performs an operation to insert a lead, and then a task/event. This is required to get your code in to production.

Comment: well noted with many thanks. Thanks again for all your help and assistance